# Why does this particular zIndex not work?

Tags: javascript, html, z-index

I am trying to build a wizard that guides people through our program and I am taking each element, put a higher z-Index on it to highlight it and add a tooltip with some helpful info.

I set the position to relative and I add the z-Index

this is the html:

```
<div id="contentContainerModule">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7" id="userProfileOverview">
               // some more thml
             </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7" id="furtherInfosProfile">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">
                        label
                    </label>
                    <div class="form-control-plaintext">
                        personnelNmbr
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    // other info
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7" id="changePassword">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">
                       username
                    </label>
                   // other div
                </div>
            </div>                
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7" id="languageSettings">
                <div class="form-group">
                   // something
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="saveButtonProfile">save</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="darkness"></div>
```

So the darkness tag is

```
darkness {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

and makes everything grey
for the button for example this works and I have position: relative on it, then i just add the zIndex of 2

but it doesn't work for the id="furtherInfosProfile" and for changePassword. It does apply the zIndex, it has position relative and almost nothing else but it is still underneath the "darkness". And I expect it to be above it.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Did you forget the # sign before id selector?

Comment: you seem to not close many of your row divs, but you need to learn about the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) - the button is not in the same stacking context as the darkness so it cannot have a higher z-index to bring it to the front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have # before the id selector. 
Also divs are transparent so you will need to add a background-color to it.

Here's a codepen link. Hopefully this answers your questions? 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gJxJra

Try

```
#furtherInfosProfile {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}
```

for the button to be visible under the darkness - It's already wrapped in a div. I just added a class of button

```
<div class="text-center button">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" 
    id="saveButtonProfile">save</button>
</div>
```

and applied this CSS

```
.button {
  z-index: 10000;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: omg thank you so much! I didn't have a background-color. That's why I couldn't see the div!

Comment: Not sure if you got the button to be visible too? I edited my answer to fix this. :)

Comment: hi, yes thank you, the button worked.. that's why i was so confused.. you're a lifesaver haha